# Get The Last Number of the Clock Time as Integer

Tags: android, time, clock

What im asking here is Not very commons & im Not even sure if this is Possible,

I know How to get the Current Device Time by using this Code(return as a String) :

```
SimpleDateFormat Date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
String DateTime = Date.format(new Date());
```

What im looking for is to Get the Last Number of the Minute as an Integer,

Eg. : The Time is 7:24 So i want to get the 4(Last Number) as an Integer,

It is Possible, if so, How ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you could work without using the SimpleDateFormat, but with the Calendar

```
int lastDigit = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) % 10;

int lastDigit = Data.getDate().getMinutes % 10; // deprecated
```

Comment: getMinutes() on java.util.date is deprecated

Comment: @AlbAtNf yeah, I remembered the second I posted... I edited it to Calendar

Comment: Add `.getInstance()` and I am happy! :P

Comment: This work too, by getting Calendar Instance first as you have mentionned, Im using SimpleDateFormat in pretty All my Code, but ill Accept your Answer as this is shorter, Thanks

Comment: I tested it, this is the second fastest solution. Substing is really slow. Calculation with System.currentTimeMillis() is often a bit faster than this solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much reputation to answer it in comments but i think what you have to do is get seconds in a variable and create sub-string and convert that string into integer.

Comment: This is what i was thinking before your Comment, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int lastMin = (int)((System.currentTimeMillis()/60000l) % 10);
```

Gives me 7 at 16:17 o'clock

Comment: I've Answered, Thanks for your Help

Answer (score 0):

I will Answer myself, the Solution was very simple :

```
    SimpleDateFormat Date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
    String DateTime = Date.format(new Date());

    int integer= Integer.parseInt(DateTime.substring(DateTime.length() - 1));

    Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(integer), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
dateTime.substring(dateTime.length() - 1, dateTime.length())
```

*Side note - the convention for Java variable names is to start with a lower case letter. You have used upper case for the first letter in your variable names. `Date.format` may cause confusion to some people as it looks like a reference to a static method in the Date class.